# Deploy a Wordpress website into Wix purchased domain

Tags: wordpress

I have a purchased Wix domain, I am having a website running there. I want to modify that website. I made a different complete website into wordpress at localhost. Can I deploy that Wordpress website into Wix purchased domain?

Comment: Did you search for any solutions on Google?

Comment: yes, didnt get any appropriate

Comment: Is this link not helpful? - https://support.wix.com/en/article/using-wordpress-with-wix

Comment: no, I have already gone through this. It is only about to add a blog.

Comment: It most probably is not possible to host the WP site as is, because Wix itself is a kind of website builder. You may need to manually change your Wix installation to make it look like your WP one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to achieve this would be to buy some alternative hosting and upload your Wordpress website to it then change the DNS settings for your domain. Wix won't let you host any other products on their servers.

Comment: yes, this is the only way. i deployed it on another domain. thanks